# Aren't enum in C++ just integers?

Tags: c++, enums, integer

I always thought that in **C++**, as well as in **C**, `enum` are just integers. But today I got this "invalid conversion from `int` to `E`":

```
enum E {
    FIRST = 0b01,
    SECOND = 0b10,
    THIRD = FIRST | SECOND  // this is fine
};

int main()
{
    E first = FIRST;
    E third = FIRST | SECOND; // this is NOT fine

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You thought wrong. Enums aren't _"just integers"_ in c++, but keep their type.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast it cause it has type int so This should achieve your goal

```
E first = FIRST;
E third = static_cast<E>(FIRST | SECOND);
```

Comment: _@Spinkoo_ Sure this would really help? I am not so ...

Comment: This was a small example, I have many logical bitwise operations to make and currently I do not see the value in using `enum` in first place if they behave this way. Better to put constants in a namespace I would say.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 In the answers of the marked duplicate there are several approaches how you could deal with that situation.